# cloth sim clipping into collision object

Tags: animation, physics

the cloth sim i am using from a cg boost tutorial isnt colliding with the bowl correctly please help, i think ive followed all the directions correctly. Please help[image]

[image]

Comment: Read the instructions here: https://blend-exchange.com/ or use a platform like workupload and in both cases share the link

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)